# Xamarin iOS - Close ViewController instance completely

Tags: c#, xamarin, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I am trying to completely close a view controller instance.
The situation is that a user will select a value on a page and will be brought back to the main page where the data updates depending on the selection.
When a value is chosen on the selection page I call

```
var vc = new viewController()
{
ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen
}
PresentViewController(vc,true,null)
```

so I am creating a new instance of the viewController so that the updated data can be displayed.
So how do I completely get rid of the previous viewController ?

One thing to also note is that viewDidLoad() is called the same number of times as the number of instances. When this gets to about 4-5 instances the app starts to get very slow. So this is the main reason I want to be able to close the instances, so I don't get repeated calls.

I know this may seem a relatively straightforward question for some but I am relatively new to Xamarin iOS.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions which can solve it .

For example ,You could set the `vc` as a property of the page so that it is a singleton in the page. And discuss it before you Present it .

```
viewController vc;
```

```
if(vc!=null)
{
  vc.DismissViewController(false,null);
}

vc = new viewController ()
{
   ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen
};

PresentViewController(vc, true, null);
```

### Update

If you `Present` a viewController in another viewController , you could discuss itself before open a new page .

#### in viewController

```
public bool IsPresent { get; set; }
```

```
vc = new viewController()
{
    ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen,
    IsPresent = true,
};
```

```
if(IsPresent)
{
  DismissViewController(false, () =>
  {
    PresentViewController(vc, true, null);
 
  });
}

else
{
    PresentViewController(vc, true, null);
}
```

Comment: This answer didn't work I am getting the exact same as I did before. I dont know if I explained the problem properly. Basically I have a page that needs to be refreshed when something is chosen but to refresh the page I have to create a new instance of the view controller so the new data will be displayed. So I am recreating the view controller over and over again and not getting rid of then before I display the new one.

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side directly .

Comment: This actually worked well after putting it in the right place. Thanks a lot my friend